# Payment Properties

Tags: properties, payment, virtocommerce

*Hello,

I create a new payment method and I need to display some properties, saved with the virtoCommerce Manager, in the Order.cshtml view.
I know I can use the GetPaymentMethod method (PaymentClient class) but I don't know how to initialize my PaymentClient paymentClient variable.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frontend is using Dependency Injection, so all you need to do is to add "PaymentClient paymentClient" to ctor method of your controller class.

For example if you have a OrderController.cs:

```
PaymentClient _paymentClient = null;
public OrderController(PaymentClient paymentClient)
{
  _paymentClient = paymentClient;
}
```

You can now use payment client object to get methods.

Comment: Well thank you. I added PaymentClient to my accountController and this allow me to get methods